# Encrypting / Encode Cookies - universal-cookie - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I've been trying to set cookies for the project I'm working on. Thing is I have no idea how to encrypt or encode them and their value shows up in the Cookies tab. [Check Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICjjd.png) I've covered some of the information in the picture. Is there a way to encrypt them? Also, I'm using universal-cookie for this task and React. Really appreciate the help. Here's the code I'm using for this...

```
function setYear() {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    let year = document.querySelectorAll('#selectedFields .year')[0].id;
    cookies.set('cookieYear', year, { path: '/'});
}
```

I'm able to get the cookies, but I would like to encrypt them as other sites do. Thanks in advance.